# Password required when deleting files from Macintosh HD

Tags: macos, permission, monterey, library

I'm trying to uninstall my Wacom drivers from my Mac and each time I try to delete any, it asks me for my password.

I think this is what is annoyingly preventing me from removing them all in one go via the EasyFind app.

Is there a way to disable this? or perhaps for me to give EasyFind permission to delete files from `Macintosh HD / Library`?

Comment: What OS, specifically & what folders show the issue? With full perms on Mojave, EasyFind tells me it can only delete immediately, not send to Trash [the action then fails.]. Have you tried something like [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) (Freeware) instead, for this type of action?

Comment: BTW, most things that required an installer to install also require an uninstaller to uninstall - Wacom's is inside the Wacom Tablet Utility - https://support.wacom.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500006264581-How-do-I-uninstall-and-re-install-the-Wacom-driver-on-Mac-OS-for-a-Pen-Tablet-Pen-Display-or-Pen-Computer-

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks, I have a vague memory of using that app many years ago but completely forgot about it!

Comment: @Tetsujin as for the wacom uninstaller, yep I do use this but annoyingly it doesn't completely remove everything and I have to manually search for all the other files to to a clean uninstall